# Three.js How to convert values to degrees in the control panel using dat.GUI?

Tags: javascript, three.js, degrees, dat.gui, radians

I made a simple slider in control panel to modify the position and rotation of an object.
I have no problem with the position, as the values are relative, but I'd like to show the rotation's values in degrees. Here is what I have in the rotation controls:

```
gui
  .add(mesh.rotation, "x")
  .min(Math.PI * -1)
  .max(Math.PI)
  .step(0.01)
  .name("Rotar en X");
```

And this is how it is shown in the control panel:

[image: COntrol panel of dat.GUI]

The idea is to show -180 and 180

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're going to have to create a placeholder object that holds the values in degrees, then [use the `.onChange()` event](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/blob/master/API.md#controlleronchangefnc--controller) to know when the value changes. That's when you can convert the degrees into radians to assign to your mesh rotation.

```js
// Placeholder holds values in degrees
var degrees = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    z: 0
};

gui
    .add(degrees, "x")
    .min(-180)
    .max(180)
    .step(1)
    // This function is called each time the value is changed
    .onChange(() => {
        console.log(degrees.x);

        // Convert the degrees to radians, then assign to mesh rotation
        mesh.rotation.x = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(degrees.x);
    });
```

I'm using [`THREE.MathUtils.degToRad()` to convert from degrees to radians.](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/MathUtils.degToRad)